# How to make plot with datetime and scipy peaks in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I took one example from a question and I adapted it to my data set, but when it comes to making plots, I got stuck. I know how to make a date time + values plot, but I didn't figure out how can I make a combination.

The response I took is the following: [Response](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/41634/80520).

The example has the following code: 
**Example Code:**

```
import numpy as np                    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks 

np.random.seed(42)

# borrowed from @Majid Mortazavi's answer
random_number1 = np.random.randint(0, 200, 20)
random_number2 = np.random.randint(0, 20, 100)
random_number = np.concatenate((random_number1, random_number2))
np.random.shuffle(random_number)

peaks, _ = find_peaks(random_number, height=100)

plt.plot(random_number)
plt.plot(peaks, random_number[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

I adapted it to my real-values dataset and I have the following code: 
**Adapted Code:**

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(my_dataset['quality'], height=500)

plt.figure(figsize=(14,12))
x = my_dataset.index
y = my_dataset.quality
plt.scatter(x, y, s=1,c='b',label='quality')
plt.plot(peaks, my_dataset['quality'][peaks], "x")

plt.xlabel('datetime')
plt.ylabel('values')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('Qualities')
plt.show()
```

Initially, my code for plotting was this and it worked:
**Initial Code:**

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,12))
x = my_dataset.index
y = my_dataset.quality
plt.scatter(x, y, s=1,c='b',label='quality')

plt.xlabel('datetime')
plt.ylabel('values')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('Qualities')
plt.show()
```

But I need to have the same plot, but with the "X" sign on the computed peaks.

So the final result should be something like this: (I edited the initial plot in paint for a visual idea of the final result)
[image: Artistic visualization of the final result]

I honestly do not know how to make it work. Can you please help me?

I highly appreciate any effort to help me!!! Thank you so much in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) of `scipy.signal.find_peaks` reports:

> **Returns**: **peaks**: ***ndarray***
> Indices of peaks in x that satisfy all given conditions.

Your `peaks` variable is an array of the **indices** of peaks. So, in order to access x and y coordinates of these peaks, you should replace:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s=1,c='b',label='quality')
plt.plot(peaks, my_dataset['quality'][peaks], "x")
```

with

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s=1,c='b',label='quality')
plt.plot(x[peaks], y[peaks], "x")
```