# IndexError: index 121383 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 117111

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy, statistics

Can you help me with this **error** please?

My **code** is:

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(my_dataset['quality'], height=500)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
x = my_dataset.index
y = my_dataset['quality']
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(peaks, y[peaks], "x")

plt.xlabel('datetime')
plt.ylabel('values')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('Qualities')
plt.show()
```

And I got this error:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-97109c9c4b15> in <module>
      3 y = my_dataset['quality']
      4 plt.plot(x, y)
----> 5 plt.plot(peaks, y[peaks], "x")
      6 
      7 plt.xlabel('datetime')
```

...
**IndexError: index 121383 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 117111**

What does it mean and how can I repair it? What should I write differently?

P.S.:
My data set looks something like this:

```
   cdf_epoch
2003-10-10 00:01:33.985000+00:00    3.294
2003-10-10 00:10:06.130000+00:00    3.294
2003-10-10 00:18:37.959000+00:00    3.917
2003-10-10 00:27:10.104000+00:00    3.116
2003-10-10 00:35:41.933000+00:00    3.383
                                    ...  
2003-11-09 23:20:19.140000+00:00    8.636
2003-11-09 23:28:50.969000+00:00    9.170
2003-11-09 23:37:23.113000+00:00    7.301
2003-11-09 23:45:54.943000+00:00    9.170
2003-11-09 23:54:27.087000+00:00    7.657
```

The "peaks" array contains the values of the data set's spikes. However, it is pretty weird as the max(peaks) gives 113940, while the max(my_dataset.quality) gives 66790.0. Shouldn't give the maximum of the spikes' values?

The "peaks" array give dataset's values, not the index. Like this:

```
array([  4112,   4117,   4124,   4126,   4131,   4135,   4137,   4139,
     4143,   4146,   4150,   4154,   4156,   4158,   4160,   4164,
     4169,   4174,   4176,   4181,   4184,   4186,   4191,   4193, ...
```

The final result I want to be like this: (I edited in paint the current histogram in order to observe the idea). So in the end I just want to put the "X" sign on the dataset's spikes' peaks.

[image: Artistic representation of the final result]

Comment: index out of bounds is telling you that your index is exceeding the size of your array

Comment: does the array means the "peaks" array ? should I put the value "-1" when it is not a real peak and then plot it ? I think this would resolve the situation as both the index and the "quality" value have the same size, just the "peaks" array is different, right? @U3.1415926

Comment: it should be your `y` array and the `peaks` values. you can test that by printing the max of peaks and the size of peaks. which is strange based on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html

Comment: Shouldn't the "find_peaks" give the spikes values (which are also the maximum values of my data set)? Because max(peaks) is 113940 , max(my_dataset.quality) is 66790.0, which is pretty weird. Also, the len(peaks) is 11952, and the len(my_dataset.index) is 117111 - this is ok.

Comment: it is always best if you can provide a minimal working example.

Comment: I edited the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who is interested in this problem, a nice user helped me in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63297589/11885185). However it does not resolve the zip problem, but it does not matter because it resolve the problem itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your `find_peaks` method returns an index that is larger than the entire array is long. Python then tries to find the 121383th number in a list of 117111 numbers. This is obviously impossible and the task fails.

The problem is probably in your `find_peaks` method. Have you checked if it really returns the index and not the y value of your peak?

Comment: it returns the y values' peaks. I want to put an "x" on the peaks on my plot. Should I record the index of the data set once the "find_peaks" method finds the peaks so it would resolve my need?

Comment: Can you add the `find_peaks` method to your question? If `max(peaks)` returns 113940 and the array has 117111 entries the Array out of bounds exception will no longer be thrown. 
You can get the index of a y value in your x data array with the `x.index(y)` method.